# How to set page number in index page?

Tags: header-footer, indexing

I am new to latex, i want to set page number to bottom of the index page. How can i achieve this?
[image]

If any one give me a sample code means that will helpful for me.

Comment: Without a minimal example, this will always be guesswork. Try `\clearpage\pagestyle{plain}` before calling the index.

Comment: I didn't get the result.

Comment: If guesswork did not help, we need a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html) to know what is going on. Fixing a motorbike is different from fixing a big lorry.

Comment: Is \setcounter{page}{1} \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}} what you wanted?

Comment: Is there any news here?